# Return an inherited type from a method

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Suppose I have the following classes defined:

```
Public Class BaseClass
    ...
End Class

Public Class DerivedClass
    Inherits BaseClass

   ... Extra Fields, methods, etc ...
End Class
```

And then, in my code, I have a function with a signature of:

```
Public Function DoSomething(...) As List(Of BaseClass)
```

And when I try and return an object of type `List(Of DerivedClass)` from it, I get the error:

`Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of BaseClass)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of DerivedClass)'`

I know not all the extra fields of the `DerivedClass` will be filled, but it would give me what I needed.

Is there a way to do this, or is this just considered bad programming practice? And, if so, what would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Understanding Covariance and Contravariance will clear things up a bit :)

- **Covariance**

Enables you to use a more specific type than originally specified.
You can assign an instance of IEnumerable (IEnumerable(Of Derived) in Visual Basic) to a variable of type IEnumerable.

**Example:**

```
IEnumerable<Derived> d = new List<Derived>();
IEnumerable<Base> b = d;
```

- **Contravariance**

Enables you to use a more generic (less derived) type than originally specified.
You can assign an instance of IEnumerable (IEnumerable(Of Base) in Visual Basic) to a variable of type IEnumerable.

**Example:**

```
Action<Base> b = (target) => { Console.WriteLine(target.GetType().Name); };
Action<Derived> d = b;
d(new Derived());
```

- **Invariance**

Means that you can use only the type originally specified; so an invariant generic type parameter is neither covariant nor contravariant. You cannot assign an instance of IEnumerable (IEnumerable(Of Base) in Visual Basic) to a variable of type IEnumerable or vice versa.

Comment: That **really** does help!! - Thank you SO MUCH!! - I'll accept the solution as soon as the timer permits.

Comment: It would be good if you could add some explanation of the key points from the link, this is barely more than a link-only answer.

Comment: Sorry to come across as a complete idiot, but I completely understood the logic of what you were saying here, Ian, but am still stuck at the implementation portion... I posted another question and I'm hoping you or someone else cold actually show me how it's done one time.. .THANK YOU AGAIN!!!!