# How to define a delegate function for Contravariance

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

In asking [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26787041/1693085), I was given an answer that I know is correct, but I still have (saldy) **no clue** how to implement it...

Suppose I have the following code:

```
Public Class BaseClass
    ...
End Class

Public Class DerivedClass
    Inherits BaseClass

   ... Extra Fields, methods, etc ...
End Class
```

And, then, in another procedure, I have the following function defined:

```
Public Function DoSomething(i as Integer, s as String, b as Boolean) As List(Of BaseClass)
  ...
End Function
```

And am using it to TRY and return both `List(Of BaseClass)` and `List(Of DerivedClass)` in my procedure, but have no clue how to do it - Even though, now I'm pretty sure (thanks to [the answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26787088/1693085)) that it would involve a delegate function call.

Could someone please show me what that code would look like?

Also, although I'm more comfortable with VB.Net, I understand C# well enough to be able to make the conversion, so either solution would be GREATLY apprecieted.

Thank you!!

---

**EDIT:**

Based upon the feedback from @Servy in his answer below, I understand that this is not about creating a Delegate function, but rather about Returning an `IEnumerable(OF BaseClass)` from my function than a `List(Of BaseClass)`. So, I changed it, but it's still not working...
I now understand why, but don't know what to do about it...

Current code:

```
Public Function DoSomething(i as Integer, s as String, b as Boolean) As IEnumerable(Of BaseClass)
    Dim RetVal as New List(Of BaseClass)
    Dim ToAdd as BaseClass
       ... some code ...
    ... loop 
        Retval.Add(ToAdd)
    ...
    Return RetVal
End Function
```

Now, I cannot change `RetVal` in my code to an `IEnumerable` since then `Add` is not allowed.

How do I do what I'm trying to do here?

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish so I post this as a comment. A strongly-typed list of `BaseClass` cannot contain elements of type `DerivedClass`. However, a strongly-typed list of `DerivedClass` can contain elements of type `BaseClass`. I'm also not sure where the function `DoSomething` reside, but how about a generic function like `Public Function DoSomething(Of TClass As BaseClass)(i As Integer, s As String, b As Boolean) As List(Of TClass)`?

Comment: And what problems do you have with your second example?  I see no reasons why it wouldn't compile, even if you changed `RetVal` to a list of derived types.

Comment: @Servy, If I try to assign it to `List(Of DerivedClass)`, I get the error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[BaseClass]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[DerivedClass]'` and if I try to assign it to an `IEnumerable(Of DerivedClass)`, I get `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[BaseClass]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[DerivedClass]'`

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, Thank you and I'm trying your solution now... Still waaay above my head, but also makes sense... But I could absolutely be barking up the wrong tree.... :/

Comment: @JohnBustos You can't assign a list of base classes to a sequence of derived classes.  You can assign a list of derived classes to a sequence of base classes.  You cannot assign a list of derived classes to a list of base classes, for reasons repeated many times.  As I said, the code that you showed will work fine.  Changing `RetVal` to be a list of derived types is fine.  The error you're getting would only arise as a result of code you haven't actually shown.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, Using your method (and probably doing EVERYTHING wrong), I did manage to get it working... THANK YOU!! - If you do post a more complete sample as a solution, I'd happily accept it!!

Comment: @servy, I don't know what I was doing wrong, but when I went the route of declaring the functions as described by Bjorn, the exact same code ended up working... I really didn't do anything differently / have more to post... I don't know how / why and **REALLY** wish I did....

Comment: @JohnBustos Bjorn's code in no way addresses the problem that you described in your question, but given your comments its quite clear that your question, and the code in it, is radically different from what you're actually doing, so who can say what's the proper way to solve the problem you haven't told us about.

Comment: @Servy, I truly do apologize... As you can see this is my second question on this topic because it so confused me and whatever I wrote was based upon the small bits I tried to understand from the first answer... I have **ZERO** doubt you are right, but I simply don't know enough to understand how to implement what you said or to understand why my code was wrong... I am a pure newbie that's trying to make it work... I can't thank you enough, though, for your help... It was just over my head as to how to implement it correctly....

Answer (score 0):

The type `List<T>` is not covariant with respect to `T`, so what you want is not possible.  To leverage covariance you'll need to use a type that supports it, such as `IEnumerable<T>`.

While delegates can themselves leverage covariance, they still require the types in question to support it.  They will do nothing to allow you to treat `List<T>` as being covariant.

Comment: Thanks for that, Servy, It took away the error, but it still didn't let me return something based on `DerivedClass`. Could you post something up showing what the actual code would look like to be able to do that?

Comment: @JohnBustos The use of delegates has nothing to do with your example at all.  If the type that your method is returning is covariant with respect to its generic argument, such as `IEnumerable<T>` (but not `List<T>`) then you can return a sequence of a more derived type.  If it doesn't support covariance then you can't.  It's that simple.

Comment: Servy, Thanks, but I'm still stuck.... I'll Update my question... It's still not working....

Comment: I wrote my exact situation in a question showing where I'm stuck... If you're willing to help, I'd love to finally understand what I'm doing wrong.... http://stackoverflow.com/q/26810591/1693085