# Returning a base OR its inherited class from the same function

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

This is my third question in a series of trying to understand how to return an inherited class from a function that is made to return the base class.

Suppose I have the following 2 classes defined in my code:

```
Public Class BaseClass
    Public a As String
    Public b As String
End Class

Public Class DerivedClass
    Inherits BaseClass

    Public d As Integer
End Class
```

And, then, in my main procedure, I have the following:

```
Dim MyDerivedList As New List(Of DerivedClass)

Sub Main()
    MyDerivedList = testing()
End Sub

Private Function testing() As IEnumerable(Of BaseClass)
    Dim retval As New List(Of BaseClass)

    Dim toadd1 As New BaseClass
    toadd1.a = "a"
    toadd1.b = "b"

    retval.Add(toadd1)

    Dim toadd2 As New BaseClass
    toadd2.a = "a"
    toadd2.b = "b"

    retval.Add(toadd2)

    Return retval
End Function
```

Based upon what I (obviously incorrectly) understood from @Servy [in his answer to a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26805438/1693085), I was assuming this would compile and run. However, I end up getting the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApplication1.BaseClass]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApplication1.DerivedClass]'
```

I was finally able to get it to work by changing it as follows based upon a comment by @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå:

```
Private Function testing1(Of TClass As {BaseClass, New})() As IEnumerable(Of TClass)
    Dim retval As New List(Of TClass)

    Dim toadd1 As New TClass
    toadd1.a = "a"
    toadd1.b = "b"

    retval.Add(toadd1)

    Dim toadd2 As New TClass
    toadd2.a = "a"
    toadd2.b = "b"

    retval.Add(toadd2)

    Return retval
End Function

Sub Main()
    MyDerivedList = testing1(Of DerivedClass)()
End Sub
```

But, I just messed around until I got it working... Based upon the comments in my earlier question, I believe I might be doing this wrong... What would the right way to do this be?

Also, I know all code was written in VB, but since the logic would be the same and I'm fairly comfortable with C#, either language would be great!

Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a sequence of base classes to a list of derived types?  The sequence isn't (necessarily) a `List`, and the base types are not derived types.  If you want to have a list of derived types then you need to create a list of derived types, not a list of base types.

Comment: @Servy, Thanks so much for sticking through this with me... The thing that's getting me is (as I commented to Bradley) - Imagine my base class was `Person` and I have, say, 3 derived classes - `Employee`, `Child` and, say, `Athlete`. My logic is to create a function that returns type `Person` and that should be able to also work for each of the derived classes and I'm getting SOOO lost as to why that wouldn't be the case... It seems my second solution allows for that, but am I just thinking this through incorrectly? - Is this cause for yet another question to post on SO for this darn issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your original sample, the mistake you made was trying to assign a list of base class objects to a list of derived ones.

Remember, you can always upcast (ok, in a generic thats not always true, but it is for `List`!), so this code is fine (and what you should be doing):

```
public List<DerivedClass> MyMethod()
{
   retList.Add(new DerivedClass());
}

IEnumerable<BaseClass> baseList = MyMethod();
```

But *not* the other way around. Clearly, this code would cause a problem (and is not allowed):

```
public List<BaseClass> MyMethod()
{
   retList.Add(new OtherDerivedClass());
}

List<DerivedClass> derivedList = MyMethod();
```

Because now the types in the assigned list are wrong!

You could *also* have gotten away with (from the first sample):

```
List<DerivedClass> baseList = MyMethod().OfType<DerivedClass>().ToList();
```

The generic code in your second sample is fine, but probably a bit confusing when you are still working with inheritance. I'd stick with the first method until you have the hang of it.

Comment: The code in your last example would just create an empty list, as none of the objects would be of the derived type.

Comment: @Servy You are correct, you would of course have to instantiate a derived class object and add it to the list for that to work. I edited a sample in.

Comment: Your first code sample, `List<BaseClass> baseList = new List<DerivedClass>();` (or `List<BaseClass> baseList = MyMethod()` or etc) will not compile.  You have to do `IEnumerable<BaseClass> baseEnumerable = new List<DerivedClass>();` since [`IEnumerable<out T>` supports covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465120.aspx).

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, Bradley, and it does make sense... The thing that's getting me is - Imagine my base class was `Person` and I have, say, 3 derived classes - `Employee`, `Child` and, say, `Athlete`. My logic is to create a function that returns type `Person` and that should be able to also work for each of the derived classes and I'm getting SOOO lost as to why that wouldn't be the case... It seems my second solution allows for that, but am I just thinking this through incorrectly? - Is this cause for yet another question to post on SO for this darn issue?

Comment: @JohnBustos You'll almost never directly return derived classes from such a function. Thats pretty much the point of inheritance. They are `Person`, and they will act as their derived classes when polymorphism dictates, but you should normally be treating them as `Person`. It *could* be another good SO question.