# Create abstract classes that contain common methods to be used from their children

Tags: c#, generics

What I'm trying to do is to create abstract classes that contain common methods to be used from their children. Because I will need a static instance reference for the children, I'm making something like

```
public abstract class Environment<T> where T : Environment<T> {

  private static T s_instance;

  public static T Instance {
    get {
      return (T)s_instance
    }
  }  
}
```

In this way if I will call the Instance property on a child, I will get the child instance and not the abstract one declaring the child as:

```
public Desert : Environment<Desert> { }
```

So if I do

```
Desert.Instance
```

I'll get the Desert instance with all its implementations and new methods (as well as the one defined in the base).
Let's say I have 2 classes like this: Environment and Animal.
Let's say I have Desert and Jungle that are 2 Environment.
Let's say I have Scorpion and Lion that are 2 Animal.
What I would like to do is to access from Environment some properties of the Animal class not knowing anything about its implementations.
Very stupid example:

1. I will instantiate a Desert (just one environment at a time will be present)
2. the Desert will have a list of animals prefabs that can be instantiated to match the species allowed there
3. as soon as it's instantiated, if no animals of that kind are already present, instantiate automatically 1 (e.g. Scorpion) and only one animal so that I can reference it with the static Instance property. No other animals will be instantiated until the one instantiated will be destroyed.

The first problem is that in the Environment I need to have a list (array, dictionary, generic list... whatever) that is defined as a list of Animal, then, it will be Desert duty to fill that list with Scorpion and others. Apparently I cannot define a structure with generic types:

```
protected List<Animal<T>> animalsList = new List<Animal<T>> ();
```

Another thing is: seeing that the action of instantiating a generic animal in an empty environment is common, I would like that my generic Environment could check if an animal has already been instantiated and, if not, instantiate one. The problem is that because Animal is generic, I cannot do

```
if (Animal.Instance == null) {
   Instantiate (animalList[Random(0, animalList.Length)]);
}
```

(please note that the previous is a pseudocode).

I hope I was not too confusing. Maybe it's the entire idea that is wrong and maybe I cannot have generics, but if you have any suggestion it's very welcome.
Thanks to everyone  :-)

**EDIT:** Why generics???
Because I was trying to make a base class with the common operations and because I need a static reference to the Instance of the children, I have defined the base classes as generic. Again, if I do this the Instance property needs to be declared just in the base class but if it when it will be called by the children, it will give back the children instance.
Examples:

```
public abstract class Environment<T> where T : Environment<T> {

  private static T s_instance;

  public static T Instance {
    get {
      return (T)s_instance
    }
  }

  public int CommonMethod () {
     return 1;
  }
}
```

and

```
public class Desert : Environment<Desert> {

   public int SandStorm () {
      return 12;
   }
}
```

and

```
public class Jungle : Environment<Desert> {

   public int Rain () {
      return 200;
   }
}
```

in my controller I can do

```
public class Controller () {

   public void CallCommonMethod () {
      Console.Write (Desert.Instance.CommonMethod ());
      Console.Write (Jungle.Instance.CommonMethod ());
   }

   public void CallSandStorm () {
      Console.Write (Desert.Instance.SandStorm ());
   }

   public void CallRain () {
      Console.Write (Jungle.Instance.Rain ());
   }
}
```

In this case it's NOT permitted to do

```
public class Controller () {

   public void CallCommonMethod () {
      Environment.Instance.CommonMethod ();
      // or
      Environment<T>.Instance.CommonMethod ();
      // or similar
   }
}
```

If instead I have

```
public abstract class Environment {

  public int CommonMethod () {
     return 1;
  }
}
```

and

```
public class Desert : Environment {

   public Desert Instance { get; private set; }

   public Desert () {
      Instance = this;
   }       

   public int SandStorm () {
      return 12;
   }
}
```

and

```
public class Jungle : Environment {

   public Jungle Instance { get; private set; }

   public Jungle () {
      Instance = this;
   }       

   public int Rain () {
      return 200;
   }
}
```

I need to define the Instance for each children. Probably I'm lazy but I thought that the generic way would be better.

Comment: Your first problem "Apparently I cannot define a structure with generic types". What does this mean? Show us the code that is not working, and explain why it is not working.

Comment: Hi ShellShock, I edited the question making an example: List<Animal<T>> animalList. sorry about that.

Comment: Why are you using a singleton pattern when you only seem to need polymorphic inheritance? Polymorphism with abstract/virtual methods will enable you to call methods in a derived object without having to know its type, you just need to know the base type.

Comment: I still don't see what purpose generics serves here.

Comment: This is the thing: because these instances will be "managed" by an external "controller", I need the static singleton references so that it will be simpler for the controller to get them when it will have the need for...

Comment: I think you should not use the singleton pattern here and have a list of animals and use all the animal objects and just Animal objects. You list can contain specific animals as well, just implement properties and methods (possibly virtual) on your Animal class.

Comment: Let me explain better: the controller will need the references of the instantiated classes so it will know that there will be a Desert and a Scorpion instantiated, but, when everything needs to be created, the generics base classes will perform the common methods that the children need when they will be instantiated.

Comment: Hi Ron. Well yes, I know that, but, as I said, I would like to be able to create something that will perform the common operation, leaving to the instances just the duty of filling the data and do extra stuff not necessary in the base, e.g. Jungle.Rain () while in the desert will not be possible.

Comment: A factory pattern may be a better fit than singleton. You should re-design the controller so it does not require singleton references; the controller should not be forcing a particular pattern onto what it is controlling.

Comment: Why is the Animal class generic? Surely the generic type is the environment? So you don't need a generic list of animals, but even if you do create a vritual property that will construct the right instance when read the first time in each descendant class.

Comment: "I would like to be able to create something that will perform the common operation, leaving to the instances just the duty of filling the data and do extra stuff". You have described classic polymorphism. Ditch your singletons and generics, you just need abstract base classes (Environment/Animal) with abstract/virtual methods which you override in the child classes. And fix your controller to work with the simpler design.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I just want to say that I'm using the generics to avoid the need to define an Instance property in every children: if I have the T Instance it will work returning the children type. If I use standard non generic abstract classes, for each children I need to re-define the Instance property by returning the child type. I just thought to have one property for everyone in the base class. I hope that this make sense to you now  ;-)

Comment: if `Desert` derives from `Environment` then you can call `Desert.CommonMethod`

Comment: Correct Patrick, but because I need to call the CommonMethod of the Animal<T> in the Environment<T> this is not allowed. In the Environment<T> I have no clues about Scorpion or Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your lazyness problem you could do something like this

```
public abstract class Environment
{
    private static Environment instance;

    public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : Environment
    {
        return (T)instance;
    }
}

public class Desert : Environment
{

}

public class class1
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Environment.GetInstance<Desert>()
    }
}
```

Comment: Be sure to create the instance somewhere and/or check for `null` inside `GetInstance`

Comment: How is `instance` created? And the cast will fail if `instance` isn't of the correct type.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the code to create the instance within the abstract generic base class.

```
public abstract class Environment<T> where T : Environment<T>, new()
{
    private static T _instance = new T();
    public static T Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; } // no need to cast here. It's already of type T.
    }

    public int CommonMethod()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class Desert : Environment<Desert>
{
    public int SandStorm()
    {
        return 12;
    }
}
```

Then usage is as you desired. `Desert.Instance.SandStorm()` and `Desert.Instance.CommonMethod()`.

Suggestions in the comments to use a factory and/or get rid of the singleton requirement are probably valid, but you were already very close to what you were looking for.

**Edit:**

You can also access the static `Instance` property like this:

```
Environment<Desert>.Instance.CommonMethod();
Environment<Desert>.Instance.SandStorm();
```

But you can't get an `Instance` until you specify the generic type. So `Environment.Instance` isn't available.

Comment: that's cool. thank you very much. before to sign this as the answer to my problem, I'll try it :-P  thank you again

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions here, but start with understanding Generic type Covariance and Contravariance:

[Return an inherited type from a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787041/return-an-inherited-type-from-a-method/26787088#26787088)

It's a very common question. This is a link to one that I recently answered.

Comment: thank you Ian. this is very useful, but it didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, this is my final solution. Please note that some of the part are in pseudocode. This is just to give you an idea of what I had in mind.

```
public abstract class Environment<T> where T : Environment<T> {

   private List<Animal> animalList;
   private static T s_instance;

   public static T Instance {
      get {
         return (T)s_instance
      }
   }

   public void ToCallInConstructor () {
      PopulateTheList ();
      if (Animal.Instance == null) {
         Instantiate (animalList.Get (defaultAnimal)); // pseudocode
      }
   }

   public int CommonMethod () {
      return 1;
   }

   public abstract void PopulateTheList();
}
```

and

```
public abstract class Animal {

   public static Animal Instance { get; private set; }

   public Animal () {
      Instance = this;
   }

    public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : Animal {
       return (T)Instance;
    }
}
```

everything else will follow the example I made in the edited part of my question in which I explained why the generics.

Thank you very much to everyone's suggestion, especially Patrick and CoderDennis.   :-)